# What is this algorithm for generating random numbers called?

Tags: algorithm, random, reverse-engineering

I have reverse engineered the follow algorithm for generating random numbers;

```
int __cdecl sub_40BB60()
{
  char v0; // si@1
  int v1; // edx@1
  int v2; // ecx@1
  unsigned int v3; // eax@1
  int v4; // edi@1
  int v5; // esi@1
  int result; // eax@1

  v0 = random_state;
  v1 = dword_685440[((_BYTE)random_state - 3) & 0xF];
  v2 = dword_685440[random_state] ^ v1 ^ ((v1 ^ 2 * dword_685440[random_state]) << 15);
  v3 = ((unsigned int)dword_685440[((_BYTE)random_state - 7) & 0xF] >> 11) ^ dword_685440[((_BYTE)random_state - 7) & 0xF];
  v4 = v3 ^ dword_685440[random_state] ^ v1 ^ ((v1 ^ 2 * dword_685440[random_state]) << 15);
  dword_685440[random_state] = v4;
  v5 = (v0 - 1) & 0xF;
  result = dword_685440[v5] ^ v2 ^ v4 ^ 32 * (v4 & 0xFED22169) ^ 4 * (dword_685440[v5] ^ ((v2 ^ (v3 << 10)) << 16));
  random_state = v5;
  dword_685440[v5] = result;
  return result;
}
```

`dword_685440` is an `int[16]`, and `random_state` is mutated as you can see.

I was thinking it may be a twister. Does anyone recognize this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it could be a [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) algorithm.  Those can be implemented at the word level by a combination of bit shifting and XOR operations, which is what this seems to be up to.

Comment: At first I was skeptical, but then I noticed all the `& 0xF`, and it makes me think you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I reverse engineered this code as well sometime ago, and thought it would be useful as reference for everyone else.

This is WELL512 random number generator. Here is an implementation: https://github.com/masfj/RNG/blob/master/WELLRNG512.cpp

If you are searching for the constant 0xFED22169, you won't find it in WELL-512. Its constant is 0xDA442D20. The code itself has been algebraically optimized by the compiler.

I had initially decompiled the same code as:

```
DWORD a = g_state[g_stateIdx];
DWORD b = g_state[(g_stateIdx - 3) % 16]; 
DWORD c = a ^ b ^ ((b ^ 2 * a) << 15);
DWORD d = (g_state[(g_stateIdx - 7) & 0xF] >> 11) ^ g_state[(g_stateIdx - 7) & 0xF] ^ c;
DWORD e = d ^ c;
g_state[g_stateIdx] = e;
DWORD f = e ^ 0x20 * (e & 0xFED22169);
g_stateIdx = (g_stateIdx - 1) % 16;
DWORD g = g_state[g_stateIdx];
DWORD h = f ^ 4 * (g ^ ((c ^ (d << 10)) << 16));
g_state[g_stateIdx] = g ^ c ^ h;
return g_state[g_stateIdx];
```

This code here:

```
DWORD f = e ^ 0x20 * (e & 0xFED22169);
```

Is the same as:

```
d  = a ^ ((a << 5) & 0xda442d20UL);
```

which has the WELL512 constant 0xda442d2d0.

```
((signed)0xda442d24 >> 5) == 0xfed2169
0x20 == 1 << 5
```

From memory, compiling one of the WELL512 source codes online, produces the exact same code under VS2013 or VS2015.

Comment: Please note that the second sentence of the [Wikipedia article on Well512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_equidistributed_long-period_linear) states that this is an LFSR.